# use of pointer to pointer in pthread_join function

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
```

According to the man page pthread_join should use a pointer to a pointer as argument to store the return value.I cant understand why its designed that way.Is it sufficient to use a pointer variable in that ?

Comment: Just because you don't understand it doesn't mean it will work if you don't follow the function's spec.

Comment: It receives the pointer you returned from your thread proc (which has a `void*` result). That value has to be stored *somewhere*. The `pthread_join` result would be a candidate, but it is used to convey the function success/failure result. Thus, an out-param is born. As an out-param in C, it provides the target as an address, thus the pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: It's designed that way so that the thread can store a void* somewhere that is not going to go away when the thread does.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your query clearly..
you should use like this..

```
pthread_t a_thread;
void *thread_result;
pthread_join(a_thread, &thread_result);
```

Comment: The bit missing is that the return value *is* a `void *`; it need not actually point to anything as it is an opaque pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The start routine you pass to `pthread_create` returns a value of type `Foobar`. I don't know what `Foobar` is, but if you want to capture that value in `pthread_join`, you have to pass a `Foobar*` in.

Now when I look at `pthread_create` documentation, I see that `Foobar` is actually `void*`. Hence `pthread_join` should accept `void**`.